# How to fix the python """ code issue in spark.sql

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am running hive query inside spark.sql by using DataFrame as shown below

```
DF1=spark.sql(""" select .........""")

import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master("yarn")\
    .appName("03_Pull_ILS_landing_attach_RETL_A.") \
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()

DF_01=spark.sql("""
select
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  where condition
"""
)
```

When I run the .py

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 1g \
--num-executors 40 \
--executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 26g \
--queue queuename \
pythonfile.py
```

I am always getting error

```
Log Length: 3249

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonfile.py", line 36, in <module>
    """
```

somewhere the closing """ is giving error.

How should I mention my hive query in DF?

Comment: "somewhere" is line 36.

Comment: Did you manage to fix BTW?

Comment: What happened here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove , before where and add table name  and Bob's your uncle. Or may be something else?